# Npm run script using if sentence

Tags: javascript, npm

I want to make npm run scirpt like this with

```
{
  "config": {
    "acc": if ({npm_config_env} == "dev") "account1" else "account_2" 
  },
   "scripts":{
     "con": "AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=${npm_package_config_acc} aws s3"
   }
}
```

when run `npm run con --env=dev` account1 should be used.

when run `npm run con --env=prod` account2 should be used.

Is it possible? I googled around but not sure npm run can use if sentence or not.

If there is any other workaround, I really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As package.json is `JSON` format file, it won't support if else or any of the programming related syntax.

One workaround for this usecase is to use if else from shell script, as `scripts` in package.json executed in shell.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "con": "AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=$(if [ $npm_config_env = dev ]; then echo \"account1\"; else echo \"account_2\"; fi) aws s3",
  }
}
```

The above script will assign value to `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` conditionally.

**Note**: As this scripts executes in shell, the script should be shell specific. The above scripts works in bash or related shells.